# jQuery change event triggered when element is built

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm building some dynamic select lists with jQuery. When they are changed, I want the event to trigger a function to get a data refresh.

```
var selector    =   $('<select id="myid" />');
selector.append($('<option value>Option Placeholder</value>'));
// attach onChange event to select list 
selector.bind('change', doUpdate(this));
```

My problem is that the `change` event gets fired every time the select list is built. I'm not sure how the trigger is happening-- I'd expect it to only trigger the `change` event when it, well, changes!

http://jsfiddle.net/TPuwc/

Comment: Just some tips: You don't need to convert the thing you want appended to a jQuery object before appending it. Also, you can string the jQuery functions together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
selector.bind('change', doUpdate(this));
```

what you're expecting to happen is to bind the event handler to execute the `doUpdate` function, passing `this` as an argument.

That isn't what's happening. Instead, what it's doing is calling `doUpdate(this)` immediately, and then attempting to set the value returned by that function call as the event handler for the `change` event.

You can simply do:

```
selector.bind('change', doUpdate);
```

jQuery will handle the value of `this` for you (it will be the element triggering the event), so you don't need to pass it in to the function as an argument.

Comment: passed parameter will be event not this(dropdown). so it will fail

Comment: @keyuratcodebins.com I already addressed that by telling them they don't need to pass `this` as an argument, because jQuery will handle that anyway. The implication is that they'll need to change their `doUpdate` function so it doesn't use the parameter, and instead just uses `this` - without seeing `doUpdate` I can't really tell them how that should look though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to understand the difference between function calls and function references. Every callback should be provided as a function reference (or an anonymous function) and not a function call.

The difference is the parentheses `()` after the function name.

```
selector.bind('change', doUpdate);
```

EDIT: Be sure to update the `doUpdate` function. It will automatically have access to the element that triggered the change using the `this` keyword, so you don't need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: passed parameter will be event not this(dropdown). so it will fail

Comment: this will fail unless doUpdate function is modified. because doUpate must be expecting dropdown as parameter. but your solution is also correct right way to do is modifying doUpdate and use this inside of that +1

Answer (score 1):

Your event arrachment method is wrong. for event attachment you should pass function. while here you are executing function and passing return value.

```
var selector    =   $('<select id="myid" />');
selector.append($('<option value>Option Placeholder</value>'));
// attach onChange event to select list 
selector.bind('change', function(){ doUpdate(this) });
```